# Next page on Selenium/Safari

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Im trying to do some web-scraping on a site, but I can't access to the next page on safari.

The site is: https://www.emol.com/todas/

the code just give me the same results of the first page twice, I need the first 3st pages

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common import exceptions
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
import os

browser = webdriver.Safari()
browser.get("https://www.emol.com/todas/")

noticias = []
i = 0
while i < 2:
    try:
        nav = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("cont_bus_txt_detall_2")

        for value in nav:
            noticias.append(value.text)

        browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href*='javascript:Next();']").click()
        i += 1

    except exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException:
         pass
```

the below code is when I inspect the button of next page on safari:

```
<a class="next current-page-next-prev" href="javascript:Next();"><span class="txt_siguiente">Siguiente</span> <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
<span class="txt_siguiente">Siguiente</span>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></I>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The thing that you are doing here is that you are refering to CSS Selector, but the selector can be the same for multiple elements, which will lead to an error or as you said, its going to be jumping into the same website, because its selector is ***static*** (same) on all websites

try this (change N, for the number you want to go ( second page == 2 ):
`browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/nav[1]/ul/li[`N`]/a").click()`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be by getting the text of the pagination elements. Here is an example for the above:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver=webdriver.Chrome()
>>> driver.get('https://www.emol.com/todas/')
>>> pagination_elements = [browser.find_element_by_xpath('//ul[@id="listPages"]/li/a[text()=%s]' % n) for n in range(1,4)]
>>> len(pagination_elements)
# 3
>>> pagination_elements[2].click() # to view page 3
```

Notice how much cleaner this is:

```
//ul[@id="listPages"]/li/a[text()=%s]
```

The "cleaner" you can make the xpaths the more resilient your scraping becomes to changes in the html. And believe me, the html changes all the time for a live site... Notice how we can easily get all the pagination elements you want here with a single line of code as well.

Finally, a much better way to scrape the page would be to inspect the network tab and get the actual data that is being emitted on that ajax call. For example, in Chrome dev tools it will give you something like this:

https://cache-elastic-pandora.ecn.cl/emol/noticia/_search?q=publicada:true+AND+ultimoMinuto:true+AND+seccion:*+AND+temas.id:*&sort=fechaModificacion:desc&size=15&from=45 (<== Note, StackOverflow doesn't markup the whole link so you'll need to copy-paste it).

This will give you json of size 15 starting from the 45th result. You can play around with the parameters there to grab the data much more easily. For example, try changing the size to "1000" and see what happens. Good luck!